# Why doesn't CMake-generated make clean delete files created with configure_file

Tags: cmake, header-files, generated, buildconfiguration

I'm using CMake for a project, and generating some configuration .h files with a `configure_file()` command. This works well enough, but - if I `make clean`, the generated file is not deleted - nor is it overwritten when I invoke `cmake` again with different parameters (or ccmake and so on).

Why is this the case, and how can I force re-generation of `configure_file` output files - when necessary / always?

Comment: `make clean` is intended to remove **build** artifacts but not **configuration** ones. `configure_file` creates the file on *configuration* stage, so that file shouldn't be cleaned. There is `make distclean` in Autotools which removes the files created on configuration stage. CMake neither provides this target nor, as far as I know, creates its own target for that purpose. With *out-of-source* build removing build directory is sufficient to clean up configuration.

Comment: Actually, there is a little reason to remove the file, created by `configure_file`, for the purpose to regenerate it. If `cmake` is called, it **always** recomputes content of the file, and rewrites the file if its current content differs from the computed one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: About your second comment - that's not what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this may happen if the files are generated under the source folder rather than under the build folder. I *think* CMake treated the (generated) files it found as source files - or at least, not build files (see @Tsyvarev's comment), so they must not be deleted/altered.